# PyQt4 dropdownlist with actions

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to create a drop down list in PyQt4, that executes an action when an element is selected. Also, some options may not be available at some time. They should still be in the list, but greyed out.

I tried attaching a menu to a QToolButton, but I can not even see the menu.
How is it done?

Thanks!
Nathan

Comment: Do you really just want a dropdown with an action being performed on selection, or do you want a button that has a menu on it?

Comment: I really want an action to be performed on selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a popup.  You can trigger a popup anywhere, using the `QMenu.exec_` method and passing the point at which you want the menu to appear.

I created a button that remembered where it was clicked, and connected that to the method to create and display the popup.

```
class MemoryButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.last_mouse_pos = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.last_mouse_pos = event.pos()
        QPushButton.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.last_mouse_pos = event.pos()
        QPushButton.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)

    def get_last_pos(self):
        if self.last_mouse_pos:
            return self.mapToGlobal(self.last_mouse_pos)
        else:
            return None

button = MemoryButton("Click Me!")

def popup_menu():
    popup = QMenu()
    menu = popup.addMenu("Do Action")

    def _action(check):
        print "Action Clicked!"

    menu.addAction("Action").triggered.connect(_action)                                                             
    popup.exec_(button.get_last_pos())

button.clicked.connect(popup_menu)
```

Answer (score 0):

QToolButton has [ToolButtonPopupMode](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtoolbutton.html#ToolButtonPopupMode-enum) enum that controls how it handles menus and multiple actions. When set to `QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup`, it will display the arrow that is typical of buttons that have menu options.

To use it set the appropriate popup mode and then you can either add a menu to the QToolButton using [setMenu](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtoolbutton.html#setMenu) or you can add actions using [addAction](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html#addAction). QToolButton should then respond as expected to clicks on the menu, whether Action generated or an actual QMenu.